# How do I add http(s) to a regular expression?

Tags: php, url

I'm like totally new at coding in general and i'm building my first website, at some point in the account creation form asks for the user's social media profile urls's. By default the .tpl file says this;

```
public function isValidUrl($url) {
    return preg_match('|^[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
    //return (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
}

public function addScheme($url) {
    $scheme = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
    || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === null ? $scheme . $url : $url;
}
```

My problem is that it requires users to copy the part of the url AFTER the "http//:www." instead of simply copy/paste the entire url from the browser's adress bar.

Could any one please tell me how to modify the above code in order to make that easier for users?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Your regex is probably not ideal -- for example, you are disallowing uppercase characters. PHP should have something built-in for URL validation, for example see `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` in http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

This is not that hard, once you get a basic understanding of the magic that's called *regular expressions*. I'd really encourage you to read a bit about it.

Something along these lines may work:

```
return preg_match('|^(http(s)?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
```

---

regex101.com is a really helpful website when working with regular expressions. Check out this [link](https://regex101.com/r/CKIBa8/1) to have your regex -- including the part that I've added -- explained.